# Deploying Lift applications on OpenShift

Tags: lift, openshift, escalante

I've tried the tutorial on the page [Deploying Lift applications on OpenShift](http://escalante.io/news/2012/10/28/lift-on-openshift/) , but I only got a blank page and it's source page is the content of the index.html which does not be rendered by the lift snippet.

So is there anything that I missed or escalante is just not support newer liftweb framework?

Comment: Have you tried posting on their public forums or on their  #escalante on freenode channel?

Comment: I solved my problem with openshift's diy platform.

Comment: What is the solution?